# How does Bootstrap Grid really work?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to understand how it works.

I made columns and put `<hr>` inside just for an illustration.

Here's what I have tried so far:

Row margin left and right -15px.
Columns padding left and right 15px.

Widths, same to bootstrap's.

Columns are floated left.

I don't understand why mine is not working? For example, 4 columns would only have 3 columns then the other one would go to the bottom. Widths are correct. I am a bit frustrated.

Edit:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="column">
  <hr>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <hr>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <hr>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.row {
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px:
}

.column {
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
float:left;
width: 33.33333%
}
```

Comment: please post code to give us an illustration of what you have done and/or tried

Comment: Edit made. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours doesn't work like Bootstrap because Bootstrap uses `border-box` sizing. To make yours work the same use..

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px:
}

.column {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333%
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/BnMCZvKZ5N

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to read more about this one. I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to acomplish, but it seems like you want 3 colums?

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        1 / 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        2 / 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        3 / 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Little explenation:
`col-md-12` is one column

so if you want 2 columns you do `col-md-6` (twice, and always bewteen a row class)

and it works the same with everything else

try reading this:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: i know this one already. the question has been answered already